# Banner in html and css width

Tags: html, css

I have one problem that I can't solve, I need my banner to be full width, not boxed. For example: the page is 1024px witdh and my banner is 800px width, now i need my banner to be 100% width. If you understand me, so, my friend and me we was trying a lot of options but we didnt figured it out.

Here is my CSS code with banner:

```
#banner{
    background-image: url(mats/banner.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 470px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
    display: block;        
}
```

I have tried everything but nothing successful.

Comment: try like this http://jsfiddle.net/bB3Uc/128/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is background-size.

```
background-size: 100%;
```

On applying this property, your background image(800px width) would strech to 1024px, which results in image quality loss.
Better applying this property on images with width > 1200px

If the height: 470px is also intended as background height, dont use it.
Never set height & width on a image, it changes the aspect ratio. If one is set, the other will auto adjust according to, else Images looks shrinked or stretched

Comment: so should i than put height: 100% and width: 100% ?

Comment: In your example,
remove >  height:470px; & width:100%;
add > background-size: 100%;

Comment: but than my image disappear, its simple, this is my design, and banner is that forest with menu, so i need that forest to be like there is on full width, not height too (http://s7.postimg.org/59rhjdedn/Untitled_3.jpg)

Comment: why dont you give jsfiddle link ?

Comment: If #banner contains nothing & if height:470px; is removed => then you cant see the background image as the container width now set to 0

Comment: your fiddle runs as expected. what to improve in the fiddle ?

Comment: With background-size property set to 100%, it is working but the image looks stretched. Correct me if I get wrong. If the image not to stretch, the image should be minimum of 1200px width

Answer (score 0):

I think you might missing background-size

```
 #banner{
        background-image: url(mats/banner.jpg);
        background-size: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 470px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        background-position: center;
        display: block;

}
```

Comment: hmm but then my banner image is zoomed and its not showing whole

Comment: this peice of code is fare enough. Problem is with the background image size (800px width). It should atleast be more than 1024px, as your screen resolution is 1024px to avoid the image stretch.

Ideally if your background image is > 1200px width, then it suits on more devices